# How to add file creation date to excel worksheet just once when a file is created

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with multiple tabs. One of the tabs is hidden and contains data to populate other tabs.

I need to add the function I found (below) to use it to add a file creation date to a cell in the hidden tab for the first time file is created. I need to execute this function just one time when file is created. The function below works well but, it executes every time I open the file.

The file can be created either Copy and Past or Save As.

Is it possible to do in VBA?

```
Public Function GeneralFileCreationDate() As Date
  Dim oFS As Object
  Dim strFilename As String

  strFilename = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  'MsgBox Format(oFS.GetFile(strFilename).DateCreated, "short date")

  GeneralFileCreationDate = oFS.GetFile(strFilename).DateCreated

  Set oFS = Nothing
End Function
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not first check to see if your hidden cell/tab already has data.  If so, skip, otherwise add the date?

Comment: ....I need to execute this function just one time when file is created.... How create the file?  .....it executes every time I open the file..... How open the file?  If don't know the logic how to help you? If you want post some code of file creation and file opening, to understand why and how the "GeneralFileCreationDate" executes...

Comment: Needs more detail on exactly how the file is "created".  Presumably you're not creating it from scratch every time, so are you saving a template file under a new name?

Comment: The problem is I dont have any control as for how new files are created. Users will either copy existing file or, use Save As dialog with a new name. Files have lots of marcros and VBA code. When newly created file is opened for the first time, new date suppose to be written to the cell on the hidden tab. To write new file creation date, I put GeneralFileCreationDate() function in the main worksheet on Workbook_Open() event. Maybe there is an event on CreateNewFile sort of thing?

Comment: Seems like the same file will always have the same creation date?  If that's the case you can get the create date using `Thisworkbook.FullName`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a UDF on your hidden worksheet, you're going to have trouble doing this once only.

However, if you're using `Workbook_Open()` anyway, I'd suggest a script like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    
    Const stamp_sheetname = "name of hidden worksheet"     'change this
    Const stamp_address = "A1"                             'and this
    
    Dim oFS As Object
    Dim strFilename As String
        
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(stamp_sheetname).Range(stamp_address) = "" Then
        strFilename = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        GeneralFileCreationDate = oFS.GetFile(strFilename).DateCreated
        Set oFS = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: If a user has copied an existing file then the cell may/will not be empty?

Comment: Yes, if you copy an already stamped file, it will contain the stamp. I don't really see a way around that. OP needs to use a template system to avoid that.

Comment: Or just read the file’s create date whenever you need it.